# Setting a finalizer function for an object in Julia

Tags: julia

I'm debugging some Julia code and trying to figure out why the following doesn't work. (julia 0.6.3)

```
struct Foo
    foo::String
end

k = Foo("bar")

finalizer(k, k->print("finalized!"))
```

While I expect it to print "finalized!", in actuality I get the following error:

```
ERROR: objects of type Foo cannot be finalized
Stacktrace:
 [1] finalizer(::Any, ::Any) at ./base.jl:127
```

I could find very little documentation on *finalizer* function, and no examples, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an answer for Julia before 0.7. If you look up `finalizer` help you will learn that the type of object must be a mutable struct.

And in particular in `finalizer` definition in *base.jl* file you can see that there is a check:

```
if isimmutable(o)
    error("objects of type ", typeof(o), " cannot be finalized")
end
```

meaning that you cannot set a finalizer for immutable objects.

In Julia 0.7 and later the syntax of `finalizer` is a bit different, but the behavior is the same, see https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/base/gcutils.jl#L15 (the order of arguments is reversed).

Here is an example with a mutable struct:

```
julia> mutable struct Foo
           foo::String
       end

julia> k = Foo("bar")
Foo("bar")

julia> finalizer(k, k->print("finalized!"))

julia> finalize(k)
finalized!
```

Comment: Anyone know the reasoning behind requiring _mutable_ here? 
As in this case - there might be an immutable string, representing a resource needing a finalizer

Comment: AFAIK garbage collector triggers finalizer, and immutable objects are not garbage collected. Actually `String` is a special case. It is immutable in the language, but actually it is treated as mutable internally by `isimmutable` function or `String.mutable` field. So you can attach finalizer to a `String` (but not to an immutable object that wraps around a `String`).

Comment: I sort of get it, but I would assume "isbits()" types are not GC'd (since they're probably stack allocated) rather than immutables. oh well, for now.

Comment: The problem with `isbits` is exactly the situation we have in the question, `Foo("a")` is not bits type, *isbits := isimmutable + contains no references* (so it is a stronger property than immutability).

Comment: Take the case of a file-handle - which can be a 'isbits' type (it's an integer), though it should be finalized ('file close'), I guess I'm looking for some RAII mechanism (and not in a 'do block' context)

Comment: This snipped does not work anymore because the order of arguments of `finalizer` has changed. Now it has to be `finalizer(k->print("finalized!"), k)`